# How would i add a leaderboard to this code?

Tags: python-3.9

[a picture of my task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de7Is.png)

Im a GCSE student whose trying to learn python. Im confused to how i would add a leaderboard to this code, i've tried a number of time but it isn't working. I've included a picture of the task i'm supposed to do. Heres the code. I've never made a leaderboard before so i don't know how to start it.

```
from random import randint

import time

count = 0

num = 0

integer = 0

score = 0

print("Welcome to the Multiplication Test")

first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ")

second_name = input("Please enter your surname: ")

Username = first_name[0:3].lower() + second_name[0:3].upper()

print("Your username is: " + Username)

print("Please write in capital letters either: -EASY- -STANDARD- -HARD-")

difficalty = input("")

if (difficalty == "EASY"):

    print("Easy mode has been selected")
    print("There will be 10 questions for you to answer")
    start = input("Press enter to start the game")
    print("the timer has started")
    begin = time.time()

    while count < 10:
        x = randint (1, 10)
        y = randint (1, 10)
        print ("The multiplication problem is ",x, "*", y)
        a = int (input ("What is your guess?"))
        count = count + 1

        if a == x*y:
            print ("That is correct.")
            end = time.time()
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("That is not correct. The correct answer is",x*y)
    elapsed = end - begin
    elapsed = int(elapsed)
    print("You got " + str(score) + " out of 10 and it took you " + str(elapsed) + " seconds")

elif (difficalty == "STANDARD"):

    print("Standard mode has been selected")
    print("There will be 10 questions for you to answer")
    start = input("Press enter to start the game")
    print("the timer has started")
    begin = time.time()
    
    while num < 10:
        x = randint (2, 12)
        y = randint (2, 12)
        print ("The multiplication problem is ",x, "*", y)
        b = int (input ("What is your guess?"))
        num = num + 1

        if b == x*y:
            print ("That is correct.")
            end = time.time()
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("That is not correct. The correct answer is",x*y)
    elapsed = end - begin
    elapsed = int(elapsed)
    print("You got " + str(score) + " out of 10 and it took you " + str(elapsed) + " seconds")

elif (difficalty == "HARD"):

    print("Hard mode has been selected")
    print("There will be 10 questions for you to answer")
    start = input("Press enter to start the game")
    print("the timer has started")
    begin = time.time()

    while integer < 10:
        x = randint (3, 15)
        y = randint (3, 15)
        print ("The multiplication problem is ",x, "*", y)
        c = int (input ("What is your guess?"))
        integer = integer + 1

        if c == x*y:
            print ("That is correct.")
            end = time.time()
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("That is not correct. The correct answer is",x*y)
    elapsed = end - begin
    elapsed = int(elapsed)
    print("You got " + str(score) + " out of 10 and you took " + str(elapsed) + " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a leaderboard as a list of `username, score` tuples:

```
# start of program
easy_leaderboard = []

# when printing the scores
easy_leaderboard.append((username, score))

# to print the leaderboard
for username, score in sorted(easy_leaderboard, key=lambda t: -t[0]):
    print(f"{username): {score}")
```

Incidentally, rather than writing out the same code three times, you could abstract it:

```py
def run_game(difficulty_name, range_min, range_max, username, leaderboard):
    print(f"{difficulty_name.title()} mode has been selected")
    print("There will be 10 questions for you to answer")
    start = input("Press enter to start the game")
    print("the timer has started")
    begin = time.time()

    while count < 10:
        x = randint (range_min, range_max)
        y = randint (range_min, range_max)
        print ("The multiplication problem is ",x, "*", y)
        a = int (input ("What is your guess?"))
        count = count + 1

        if a == x*y:
            print ("That is correct.")
            end = time.time()
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("That is not correct. The correct answer is",x*y)
    elapsed = end - begin
    elapsed = int(elapsed)
    print("You got " + str(score) + " out of 10 and it took you " + str(elapsed) + " seconds")
    leaderboard.append((username, score))
```

Comment: so where would i write the code you said in the code i have written so far?

Comment: You'd need to set up a leaderboard when the program starts - one for each difficulty level. When your player finishes a game, you'd want to add their name and score to the leaderboard at that point, and maybe display it straight away. The guidance mentioned a menu, so you might want to also have a "display leaderboard" option there. Good luck btw - not sure Python existed when I was doing GCSEs!

Comment: ahh thank you! the guidance said it should be stored externally, how would i do that?